Assistant on Android Go does not support App Actions.what is alternative approach to open app through google assistant in all android Phone?
I'm working on app actions to open my app through Google Assistant. It works fine on all Android phones except Android Go Edition. Additionally, it forces me to open the app with the command, "Hey Google, open on Example app,"
However, I want it to open my app with the command, "Hey Google, open Example," without adding the keyword "on" or something else like "from."
I want to be able to open the app using Google Assistant on all Android phones, including Android Go Edition.
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <shortcut
        android:shortcutId="open"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/app_name"
        android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/shortcut_long_label">
        <capability-binding android:key="actions.intent.START_EXERCISE">
            <parameter-binding
                android:key="exercise.name"
                android:value="@array/actionSynonyms"/>
        </capability-binding>
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetClass=".VoiceActivity"
            android:targetPackage="com.actions.ExampleApp"/>
    </shortcut>
</shortcuts>

Android Manifiest file:
<activity android:name=".VoiceActivity" android:exported="true">
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts" android:resource="@xml/shortcuts"/>
</activity>

String Array:
<string-array name="actionSynonyms">
    <item>add</item>
    <item>remove</item>
    <item>open</item>
</string-array>

Link of Google assistant: https://developer.android.com/develop/devices/assistant/overview
